# Not getting data properly with speical character in xml

Tags: android, xml, parsing, android-xmlpullparser

I am creating application in which I get xml from server which contain special character when I parsed it at  android side i get different string of single string which contain special character 
Here is example of generated xml :

```
<field>
<option>Didn&apos;t Apply For Card,Do Not Want the Card,No</option>
<validation>NA</validation>
<field_name>self_closed</field_name>
</field>
```

Here is my code :

```
    String tagname,value = null,t_name;
    t_name=table_name;
    XmlPullParserFactory xmlPullParserFactory = null;
    XmlPullParser xmlPullParser = null;

    //System.out.println("In parse UI table name:"+table_name);
    result=input_stream;
    try {
        xmlPullParserFactory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
        xmlPullParserFactory.setNamespaceAware(true);
        xmlPullParser = xmlPullParserFactory.newPullParser();
    //System.out.println("Load file :"+result);
        xmlPullParser.setInput(result,"UTF-8");
        //xmlPullParser.defineEntityReplacementText("&#38;","&");
        int eventType = xmlPullParser.getEventType();
        while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) 
        {
                    tagname=xmlPullParser.getName();     
                  if(eventType==XmlPullParser.START_TAG) 
                  {

                  }
                  else if(eventType==XmlPullParser.TEXT)
                  {
                      value=xmlPullParser.getText();
                      if(value.isEmpty())
                      {
                          System.out.println("string is empty");
                      }
                      value=conversion.add_special_character(value);
                      System.out.println("value:"+value);
                      value=value.trim();

                    System.out.println(" text tag value :"+value);
                  }
                  else if(eventType==XmlPullParser.END_TAG) 
                  {
                      if(tagname.equals("field"))
                      {
                          //System.out.println("field"+field+" table name:"+t_name);
                          dbController.insert_into_fields(field, t_name);
                          //database.insert_into_fields(field);
                          field.clear();
                      }
                      if(tagname.equals("field_name"))
                      {

                          field.put("field_name", value);

                      }
                      if(tagname.equals("type"))
                      {
                          field.put("input_type", value);
                      }
                      if(tagname.equals("label"))
                      {
                          field.put("label", value);
                      }
                      if(tagname.equals("option"))
                      {
                          //System.out.println("in option tag option:"+value);
                          field.put("option", value);
                      }
                      if(tagname.equals("validation"))
                      {
                          //System.out.println("In validation tag:"+value);
                          field.put("validation", value);
                      }
                     // System.out.println("Tag_name :"+tagname);
                  } // end of else end tag

             eventType = xmlPullParser.nextToken();
        }// end of while loop
        dbController.close_database();
    } // end of try
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        // TODO: handle exception
        e.printStackTrace();
    } // end of catch
```

when I parse it instead of getting "Didn't apply for card" as whole string I get it as two different string "didn " and t apply for card

Comment: `xmlPullParser.setInput(result,"UTF-8");` That is where you give the xml to the parser i suppose. I don't know how to fix it but i would do the folowing tests if i were you. Do a string replace on result before you give it to the parser. Change "&apos;" to "'" for a first test. But it looks as if the parser recognizes an "'" so the second test i would do is replace "&apos;" by "\\'".

Comment: Have a look at html entities. http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_entities.asp There is a class in java which you can use for it also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use this code for parsing xml:

```
   XmlPullParserFactory factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
   factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
   XmlPullParser  parser = factory.newPullParser();
   parser.setInput("xml input stream", null);

        int eventType = parser.getEventType();
        while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
            String tagname = parser.getName();
            switch (eventType) {
            case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:
                if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase("field")) {
                }
                break;

            case XmlPullParser.TEXT:
                text = parser.getText();
                break;

            case XmlPullParser.END_TAG:
                if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase("field")) {

                }  else if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase("option")) {
                     System.out.println(text);
                } 
                break;

            default:
                break;
            }
        }

    } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {e.printStackTrace();} 
    catch (IOException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
}
```